# Add 'expand details' button on Devexpress gridcontrol cell

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a gridcontrol with a few columns. I want a way to expand a specific cell, displaying a popup with additional information.

Basically, the column is 'Message', which is of type string, and I want to be able to click on individual cells in this column and display a popup with additional details. It is a Devexpress gridcontrol.

I was thinking of button with a little plus sign to expand this view, on each cell.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [RepositoryButtonEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemButtonEdittopic) and handle the Click event:

```
private void buttonEdit1_ButtonPressed(object sender, ButtonPressedEventArgs e) {
    ButtonEdit editor = (ButtonEdit)sender;
    int buttonIndex = editor.Properties.Buttons.IndexOf(e.Button);
    if (buttonIndex == 0) 
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Aditional details");
    }
}
```

more info [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemButtonEdit_ButtonPressedtopic) and [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemButtonEdit_ButtonClicktopic)

Comment: Thanks Jens - im working on it, will mark your answer when im done.

Comment: Awesome, looks like it will do the job, thanks again